# Supporting iPhone 6 and 6 plus

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xib, iphone-6

My app is built for iOS 7.
When I opened it with Xcode 6 I fixed the interface to look good for the 4.7 and 5.5 inch displays.
But it does not seem to work, I still see a 4" design on my iPhone 6 and simlator.
Is there any setting I need to change to make it work with iPhone 6 and 6 pulse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have gotten a warning from the compiler. You need to include a splash screen xib file to support iPhone 6 & 6+